# ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using rails 4 + activeadmin runing on ruby 1.9.3p392.

When I'm going to the

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin/login
```

uri I get an error:

> ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new
>
> Showing C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-85b9f8164809/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #5 raised:
>
> wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
<h2><%= title "#{render_or_call_method_or_proc_on(self, active_admin_application.site_title)} #{t('active_admin.devise.login.title')}" %></h2>

<% scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_name) %>
<%= active_admin_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => send(:"#{scope}_session_path"), :html => { :id => "session_new" }) do |f|
  f.inputs do
    resource.class.authentication_keys.each { |key| f.input key, :input_html => {:autofocus => true}}
    f.input :password
```

Comment: For anyone who is getting this in Rails 6 refer to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65814105/11001474

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had the same problem here and i solved removing **gem "meta_search"** from my Gemfile.