# ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

ArgumentError in ActiveAdmin::Devise::Sessions#new
Showing /home/tshegyel77/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activeadmin-2.9.0/app/views/active_admin/devise/sessions/new.html.erb where line #8 raised:

wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

rails 6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftXSy.png)

Answer (score 0):

[This is the most recent issue raised on the ActiveAdmin project](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/6671).

To summarise, it seems the issue is compatibility between `formtastic` and ruby `v3.0.0`.

The solution is to upgrade `formtastic` to at least version `4.0.0.rc1`. (Or to keep using ruby 2.7, for now.)